# Silverlight Start up life cycle and binding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

This is the first time I have used Silverlight and as such, I am new to the whole xaml markup style. I am building a GIS application using a silverlight library provided by ESRI.

From my understanding, when the XAML page is parsed from top to bottom, the objects are created in the order. Is this correct? I have an esri Map object created on line 38 of my mainpage and then on line 247 of my mainpage, I create a DrawControl (a drawing control I made myself).

Part of how the objects in drawing tool works is that it is created by passing the map object to the constructor. With my Map object with name x:Name="Map", I have the following for my drawcontrol:

```
<local:DrawRootControl x:Name="DrawRoot" Height="152" Margin="216,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" map="{Binding ElementName=Map}"/>
```

Then in my control, I have this in the code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty mapProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
             "map",
             typeof(Map),
             typeof(DrawRootControl),
             null
        );

    public Map map
    {
        get { return (Map)GetValue(mapProperty); }
        set { SetValue(mapProperty, value); }
    }
```

..........

```
public DrawRootControl()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();

        MyDrawObject = new Draw(map)
        {
            LineSymbol = CanvasDraw.Resources["DrawLineSymbol"] as LineSymbol,
            FillSymbol = CanvasDraw.Resources["DrawFillSymbol"] as FillSymbol
        };
        MyDrawObject.DrawComplete += MyDrawObject_DrawComplete;             
    }
```

When I am debugging, my map object in my constructor is null. I thought that if map is created earlier in the mainpage and then passed when I do that binding, it would not be null and would be initialized and created. Maybe I am doing binding incorrectly? I don't really understand the binding thing entirely.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Databinding doesn't occur until after initialization.  Which makes sense, as there would be nothing to bind to if the control wasn't constructed yet

Comment: You're not actually using databinding at all. You're just manually setting a property.

Comment: Ok, when do I know when the itialization is over? Joe, I made the binding in my xaml (first code snippit at the end) map="{Binding ElementName=Map}"

Comment: Ah, I missed that -- sorry. As for how you know initialization is over, the most robust way is to do your initialization when the property value is assigned.

Comment: So, would the best way to do that would be to add it programmatically in the code behind after InitializeComponent() for mainpage so I know my map object is fully setup? Would there be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, when the XAML page is parsed from top to bottom, the objects are created in the order. Is this correct?

yes top to bottom like html.  Example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFE53400" Height="132"  />
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF0000E5" Height="132" Margin="0,51,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

> Part of how the objects in drawing tool works is that it is created by passing the map object to the constructor.

If you are dependent to another UI element you will need to implement the callback to draw your control when the DependencyProperty has changed.  In this example replace Title with Map

```
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(ComparisonReport), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTitleChanged));

    private static void OnTitleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var o = d as ComparisonReport;
        if (o != null && e.NewValue != null)
        {
            var n = ((ComparisonReport)d);
            n.RadChart1.DefaultView.ChartArea.AxisX.Title = String.Format("{0} Comparison", e.NewValue);
        }
    }
```

If you have written a custom control you can wait till OnApplyTemplate() at which point you can locate the part (esri map object) by name.  GetTemplateChild you can then attach to the esri events that affect your custom drawing.

Comment: On the OnTitleChanged event, at which point is it changing the title to the new value?

Comment: Also, is there a way to make the OnTitleChanged no static as I want to reuse the control and if I am having to set the map inside this fuction, I would be forced to use a static property for that as well.

Comment: <local:DrawRootControl x:Name="DrawRoot" Height="152" Margin="216,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" Title="{Binding ElementName=title}"/>   any time this binding is updated it would cause OnTitleChanged to be called.  static is due to the framework you will have to use "d" which is the specific instance of your class; example in my case I use d to cast to the specific report so i can update the axis title

Comment: Big thanks man walking me through this. i got it working now!